# Azure functions proxies.json file not taking any effect

Tags: azure, azure-functions

i created a sample azure function and added a proxies.json file with following contents.

[image]

when i run the function app locally and hit http://localhost:7071/api/items nothing is returned.
it looks like proxies file is not taking effect.
am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

soon after posting the question i figured out that i had to set proxies file as "Copy Always" in "Copy to output directory" setting of the file in visual studio.